# Applying htmlentities ENT_QUOTES on array

Tags: php

I have an array $fields:

```
Array
(
    [NAME] => M'y Na'me
)
```

I want to convert those apostrophes to entities. When I run:

```
array_map('htmlentities', &$fields, array_fill(0 , count($fields) , ENT_QUOTES) );
```

and then `print_r $fields` nothing seems to have changed?

```
Array
(
    [NAME] => M'y Na'me
)
```

How can I apply htmlentities with `ENT_QUOTES` on all elements in `$fields`?

EDIT: this makes me lose my keys

```
$fields = array_map('htmlentities', $fields, array_fill(0 , count($fields) , ENT_QUOTES) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs `array_map` returns a new array and doesn't modify the one passed in in-place.

```
$fields = array_map(
    'htmlentities', &$fields,
    array_fill(0 , count($fields) , ENT_QUOTES)
);
```

EDIT according to comment --

Since this is PHP, I suppose the best way is to forego the functional route and do it the old-school way:

```
foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
    $fields[$key] = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: This converts my keys to numeric ones

Comment: Added the obvious alternative solution, @stef

Answer (score 1):

`array_map` does not modify the array, even if you pass it as reference.
Use `$fields = array_map('htmlentities', $fields, ...)` instead.